# XIB not supported for iphone of 3.5 inches

Tags: iphone, constraints, autolayout

I have coded the app using XIB of 4.0 inch, when I run it in iphone with 3.5 inch the UI gets bad.

I am not using auto layout. So Now I want to know what should I Do to fix this issue ??

Comment: your question may well be closed or voted down if you do not show some code and screen grabs.

Comment: Use separate xib files for each type of inches, then load them accordingly by checking screen height in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use auto resizing or u can make separate xibs for both